# Gcloud sql proxy startup script runs but gives out an error

Tags: mysql, proxy, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Here is my startup script:

```
#! /bin/sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
sudo mkdir /cloudsql; sudo chmod 777 /cloudsql
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql --instances=a:us-east4:b &
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Feb 19 22:12:38 instance-group-1-th2f startup-script: INFO startup-
script: 2019/02/19 22:12:38 errors parsing config:
Feb 19 22:12:38 instance-group-1-th2f startup-script: INFO startup-script: #011Get https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/a/instances/b?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: dial tcp: lookup www.googleapis.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52058->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
Feb 19 22:12:38 instance-group-1-th2f startup-script: INFO startup-script: 2019/02/19 22:12:38 Ready for new connections
```

If I open the instance manually and run the following, it will work:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=a:us-east4:b &
```

I am guessing that it is an authentication problem, but based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine):

> Note: If your Compute Engine instance has either the Full API access
>   or Cloud SQL API scope, you can skip this step; you do not need to
>   provide a certificate file when you start the proxy.

It shouldn't have any problems since mine has a Full API access

I have a second gen instance and the Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
dial tcp: lookup www.googleapis.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52058->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

It doesn't look like your issue is authenticated related, but instead you are unable to either lookup or reach `www.googleapis.com`. Do you have a firewall that might be blocking the outgoing connection?